# Access an xterm window open on local machine , remotely via ssh

Tags: ssh, xterm

I have an xterm window open on a computer. I want to access this xterm window remotely using ssh. Is it possible? By access I mean, I should be able to run commands on that open shell.

Comment: If that shell is already running then the only way I see is by starting some sort of listener inside that shell, so a mini server you connect to. Bit very common. If however you want to start a shell for the purpose then you have multiple alternatives.

Comment: The shell is already running. And I would like to get into it and work on it remotely. How does one place the 'listener' in the xterm?

Comment: You can't. [Why do you want to do this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) There may be some other way of doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: So, I acquire nodes on a cluster via qrsh with a bash shell as stdin. I dont want to lose the nodes by closing the shell and want to be able to work on them from a remote location. Hence the problem. Any advice on changing the stdin for more flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to access an xterm window that's already been opened, while being over ssh. However, you can certainly open an ssh connection with X11 forwarding capabilities. Once X11 is forwarded, you can just run the program in ssh's command line, and it'll open in your forwarded X11 screen.

Here's a good article that explains in detail what you need to accomplish this: http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html

For example, after completing the details in the above article, and assuming you have Gnome Desktop installed, you could run `gnome-terminal` over ssh and have a Unix terminal open and forwarded over the ssh connection. Pretty much any application that has a GUI is runnable this way.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to access a specific xterm open on a system.